# Почему созданная функция не может быть использованна? (Python 3.4.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал такой код:

```
innum = input("Введите число: ")
i = 0
innum = int(innum)
res = OnWhatNumberDivides(innum)
count = len(res)

while i < count:
    print(res[i])
    i+=1


def OnWhatNumberDivides(num):
    """ Usage: OnWhatNumberDivides(<num:int>) -> List of int
        Searching on what number divides and pushing it to array"""
    inn = num
    for inn in range(0,num+1):
        res2 = 0
        i += 1
        res = innum / i
        res2 = res
        result = []
        if i == (int(innum)+1):
            del res
            del res2
            del i
            del inn
            return result


    if int(res2) == res:
        result.push(res)
    del res
    del res2
```

При запуске и вводе числа выбивает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Python3.4\MyPythonScripts\На что делиться число.py", line 4, in 
    res = OnWhatNumberDivides(innum)
NameError: name 'OnWhatNumberDivides' is not defined
```

Что делать?

Comment: На момент использования функция еще не объявлена. Как вариант, можно переместить её выше всего остального кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать вот так:

```
def OnWhatNumberDivides(num):
     ....


def main():
    innum = input("Введите число: ")
    i = 0
    innum = int(innum)
    res = OnWhatNumberDivides(innum)
    ....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Таким образом, точкой входа, при исполнении вашего скрипта (вызове его из консоли), всегда будет функция `main()`. И учтите, что порядок следования конструкции `if __name__ == '__main__':` важен, т.е. она должна быть в самом конце скрипта, после объявления всех функций.

Дело в том, что Python с первых же строчек скрипта начинает его исполнять (интерпретировать), не удосуживаясь предварительно "прочитать" его до самого конца. Вот и получается, что поскольку функция `OnWhatNumberDivides` была определена ниже по коду, до сего момента (до текущей исполняемой строки скрипта) она является не объявленной (not defined).

Используя же приём, как показано выше, мы заставляем интерпретатор волей-не-волей "прочитать" код нашего скрипта до самого конца, ознакомиться со всеми объявлениями функций/классов/ и проч. и только потом начинать что-то делать. Но даже в этом случае, Python не будет заглядывать внутрь самих функций и как-то их проверять, до того момента, пока он не доберётся непосредственно до исполнения конкретной строки в конкретной функции.

Comment: Как бы, с одной стороны код будет работать, с другой стороны наличие функции `main` и `if __name__ == '__main__':` не является необходимым для этого условием.

Comment: Да, но лучше всегда писать так, как указано выше. Тогда не нужно будет заботиться о соблюдении порядка объявления функций, да и читается такой код легче.

Comment: можно всегда писать функции выше, тогда все будет работать. И читается такой код будет не намного сложнее, чем показанный в ответе. К тому же, в вашем варианте можно саму функцию `main()` переместить куда-нибудь между другими функциями (которых может быть десяток), и читаемость сойдет на нет. Это как контраргумент. На самом деле, `if __name__ == '__main__':` в некоторых случаях нужно использовать, но в этом конкретном случае - не обязательно.

Comment: По сути вы даете просто готовое решение, а ответ, почему именно не работает, вы скрываете за кодом. Нам с вами он кажется очевидным, но новичку он не так уж очевиден.

Comment: в общем-то я дуб дубом в Python но всё равно не читая ваш комментарии выше я понимаю **Как и почему это работает**

Comment: @WarSpaker, ответ предназначен не только для вас, но и для всех, у кого возникнет аналогичный вопрос. Поэтому в ответе желательно разъяснить так, чтобы все было действительно очевидно.

Comment: @insolor Дополнил ответ.